# python google oauth restrict for domain users only

Tags: python, google-authentication

My company manage the internal employee login with google.
I’ve created a flask app on top of google bigquery that should be only available to the company employees.
I’ve followed [this manual](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/web-app) to authenticate the employees but if a gmail private user login, it still passes. How can I make sure that only company’s employees login to the app?
I thought about checking the domain of the email but I couldn’t find good example of fetching the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I acquired the email using `email` scope.

First enable `Google People API` if not already enabled as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#acquiring-and-using-an-api-key)

After that add `email` to your scope list and send a request, like this (in python):
`get_user = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={}'.format(credentials._id_token))`

If the call was successful you can extract the email in order to check its domain:
`json.loads(get_user.text)['email']`